# Mongoose error - elemMatch() must be used after where() when called with these arguments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
UserSchema = new Schema({
  'username': { type: String, validate: [validatePresenceOf, 'a username is required'], index: { unique: true } },
  'hashed_password': String,
  'salt': String,
  'locations': [LocationSchema]
});

LocationSchema = new Schema({
  'lat': Number,
  'lng': Number,
  'address': { type: String, validate: [validatePresenceOf, 'The address is required in order to add a new location.'] },
  'name': String
});
```

I'm trying to find a particular single location document by it's id. To do this I'm attempting to query the users collection items by location key, which is an array of location documents. My query looks like this:

```
var query = User.find({"locations.$": 1})
                .where()
                .elemMatch({locations: {_id : ObjectId('531283690315992f05bcdc98')}})
                .exec(function(err, data){

                  console.log(err);
                  console.log(data);
                });
```

When it runs I get the following error:

Error: elemMatch() must be used after where() when called with these arguments

What does this mean? I can't seem to find a good explanation.

Forgot to mention, I can get the data I want from the mongo shell by running the following: `db.users.find({locations: {$elemMatch :  {_id : ObjectId('531283690315992f05bcdc98')}}}, {"locations.$": 1});`

Comment: why are you specifying elemMatch at all?  It's only needed when you are providing it more than one condition to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a path to your `where` call and reorder things a bit:

```
User.find()
    .where('locations')
    .elemMatch({_id : ObjectId('531283690315992f05bcdc98')})
    .select({'locations.$': 1})
    .exec(function(err, data){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
```

But you could also simplify it somewhat as you don't need to use `$elemMatch` here and you can let Mongoose take care of the casting:

```
User.find()
    .where('locations._id', '531283690315992f05bcdc98')
    .select({'locations.$': 1})
    .exec(function(err, data){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
```